# How to pass to stay in hex values for background color on Firefox (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, email, firefox, background, background-color

I'm currently using JQuery to assign colors to containers.

In Chrome and IE, when I get innerHTML the background color stays "**background-color:#333333**". But in Firefox, it's replaced with "**background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(X, X, X)**".

The problem is that I'm using the html in a form submit and I want to keep `background-color` notation because in email like Hotmail, `background` gets removed from the content.

For now, I think the best solution may be to use "bgcolor" instead of css background-color.

Can someone help me ? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the style directly on the DOM element and see if that gives the correct result in Firefox:

```
$('#YOUR_ID').get(0).style.backgroundColor = '#333333';
```

Comment: True, for an element with id, SKS example would be the fastest. If you have multiple elements you have to use .each(), e.g. $('div.colorize').each(function() { this.style.backgroundColor = '#333333'; });

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. In my each() loop, I use `jQuery(this).get(0).style.backgroundColor = value;` and when I inspect the element, I still get `background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(204, 53, 53);`

Comment: Then I guess it's a Firefox internal thing and hard to circumvent. You could try setting the complete shorthand css('background', '#333333') instead of css('background-color', #333333); and see if that fixes things.

Comment: I already tried this and still no success. Finally, I used `jQuery(this).attr('bgcolor', value)` instead of `jQuery(this).get(0).style.backgroundColor = value`. And to avoid conflict between css and bgcolor, I get rid of background with `jQuery(this).css('background', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Just found a good way using the .attr() method after having no luck with the other solutions.  This is only helpful if you are setting a single style property, however, since it will overwrite existing inline style.

```
$(element).attr('style', 'background-color: #f00');
```